# Forcefully stop a process (e.g., webbrowser.open) in Python, including a pygame example

Tags: python

I am working on a Python script that involves opening a web page using webbrowser.open(). I want to have the ability to forcefully stop the process of opening the web page from another script or method.

Additionally, I noticed a similar mechanism in a library like pygame, where setting an environment variable before importing hides a support prompt:

```
import os
os.environ['PYGAME_HIDE_SUPPORT_PROMPT'] = "hide"
import pygame
```

Is there a way to achieve a similar behavior for stopping the opening process? I would like to conditionally prevent the opening of the web page based on some external condition, similar to how the PYGAME_HIDE_SUPPORT_PROMPT variable affects the behavior of pygame.

I am currently using the following code to open the web page:

```
from webbrowser import open
open('https://google.com')
```

What modifications or alternative approaches can be used to forcefully stop this process from another script or method? Any insights or examples, especially regarding the integration of such a mechanism similar to PYGAME_HIDE_SUPPORT_PROMPT, would be highly appreciated.